# C# IQueryable or AsQueryable

Tags: c#, interface, repository, iqueryable

I'm prototyping some sort of repository and I want to know if it's enough to have methods, that operate on *sequences* **only**.

For example:

```
public void AddEntities<T>(IQueryable<T> sequence);
```

Now, this method prototype seems fine and really *generic*, but it sucks when somebody wants to do something like:

```
var t = new T();
// Add just a single entity.
repository.AddEntities(???);
```

*What are the solutions for this case?*

Should I make my interface larger and add methods like `AddSingleEntity<T>(T t)` and `RemoveSingleEntity<T>(T t)` or should I leave it as it is and use something like:

```
repository.AddEntities(new List { new T() }.AsQueryable());
```

*Both choices obviously have drawbacks:* the first one makes the interface uglier and less compact, the second simply looks a bit weird.

**What would you do and why?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would create additional methods to handle single entities operations, because it will look cleaner and a lot of common interfaces do it (List)

EDIT: what I do if I want to have only one method group:

```
public void Add<T>(IEnumerable<T> entities) { ... }

public void Add<T>(params T[] entities) { this.Add(entities.AsEnumerable()); }
```

you can now call:

```
repo.Add(entity);
repo.Add(entity1, entity2);
repo.Add(entityList);
```

Comment: List was designed before generics, so if someone called `.Add()` with an array, there's no way for List to know if you want to add all the elements in the array to the list, or add the array itself to the list.  With generics, separate methods are unnecessary, because `Add<T>(T t)` and `Add<T>(IEnumerable<T> t)` are unabiguous.

Comment: +1 for your edit, however (though I would switch the calls around, so you don't have to call `.ToArray()`)

Comment: actually i'm talking about the generic list but the html hide my <T>.Anyway, my examples are not from List but something he could implement in his repo

Answer (score 2):

why not to add `repository.AddEntity(T t)`? Simple and nice. Looks like overengeneering a bit.

Answer (score 2):

I would not operate with IQueryable in this particular case. It's a query.
Read [this](http://www.weirdlover.com/2010/05/11/iqueryable-can-kill-your-dog-steal-your-wife-kill-your-will-to-live-etc/) useful article. Use IEnumerable when sending data.